# Нужна сортировка массива 5х2 (5 звеньев), чтобы получилась цепочка

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, сортировка, список

Нужен принцип сортировки для массива типа:

```
ids = [[22,33],
       [44,55],
       [33,44],
       [11,22],
       [55,66]]
```

чтобы в результате вышло:

```
res = [[11,22],
       [22,33],
       [33,44],
       [44,55],
       [55,66]]
```

Числа могут быть любыми главное условие чтобы вышла цепочка

```
11,22 ~> 22,33 ~> 33,44 ~> ...
```

Не обращайте внимание на первые цифры, они не важны.

вот пример списка

```
ids = [[203, 11], [1, 203], [5001, 1], [333, 22], [22, 5001]]
```

а вот как он должен выглядеть:

```
ids = [[333,22], [22,5001], [5001,1], [1,203], [203,11]]
```

образуется цепочка `ids[0][1] = ids[1][0], ids[1][1]=ids[2][0] ...`

Comment: Добавте пожалуйста ваш код.

Comment: Вот то, что не важны первые числа нужно было указать сразу, а не писать в отдельном сообщении, а потом редактировать вопрос

Comment: @KitScribe полностью согласен.

Comment: В обоих примерах искомая цепочка - однозначна. Т.е. все первые и все вторые значения уникальны. Это гарантируется  условием задачи? Также, что означает "не обращайте внимание на первые цифры, они не важны"???

Comment: @AnT Изначально предложили сортировку по первым цифрам, по возрастанию. И встроенная функция sort() делает аналогичную операцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача по составлению цепи из заданного массива звеньев это частный случай нахождения [Гамильтонова пути в графе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84), заданном набором рёбер -- каждое звено это ребро между двумя вершинами в направленном графе.

Так как звенья являются частью Гамильтонова пути, то каждая вершина имеет не более одного входящего и исходящего ребра и чтобы найти путь, достаточно попробовать все рёбра в качестве начального звена и вернуться когда все звенья использованы:

```
def hamiltonian_path(edges):
    for link in edges: # try all edges as the starting point
        left = {link[0]: link for link in edges} # left -> link
        left.pop(link[0], None) # remove the first link (cut the cycle)
        chain = []
        while link:
            chain.append(link)
            link = left.pop(link[1], None) # right -> left
        if len(chain) == len(edges): # found Hamiltonian path
            return chain
    raise ValueError('failed to find Hamiltonian path for ' + str(edges))
```

Это квадратичный алгоритм. Примеры:

```
>>> ids = [[22,33],
...        [44,55],
...        [33,44],
...        [11,22],
...        [55,66]]
>>> hamiltonian_path(ids)
[[11, 22], [22, 33], [33, 44], [44, 55], [55, 66]]
>>> ids = [[203, 11], [1, 203], [5001, 1], [333, 22], [22, 5001]]
>>> hamiltonian_path(ids)
[[333, 22], [22, 5001], [5001, 1], [1, 203], [203, 11]]
```

Заметив, что начальная вершина не является исходящей ни в одном из звеньев (если нет цикла), можно линейный алгоритм реализовать:

```
def hamiltonian_path(edges):
    chain = []
    if not edges: # empty
        return chain

    # edge == (inbound, outbound)
    inbound = {edge[0]: edge for edge in edges}   # inbound -> edge
    outbound = {edge[1]: edge for edge in edges}  # outbound -> edge

    # find the first link 
    try:  # its inbound vertice is not present in any outbound vertices
        link = next(inbound[v] for v in inbound if v not in outbound)
    except StopIteration: # edges form Hamiltonian cycle (graph)
        link = inbound.pop(edges[0][0]) # use any edge

    # build chain
    while link:
        chain.append(link)
        link = inbound.pop(link[1], None) # outbound -> inbound
    if len(chain) != len(edges):
        raise ValueError('failed to find Hamiltonian path for %s (got %s)' % (
            edges, chain))
    return chain
```

Результаты для примеров те же.

Comment: Так а откуда взято утверждение о том, что путь гамильтонов и каждая вершина "имеет не более одного входящего и исходящего ребра"? Я не вижу в постановке задачи ничего, что запрещало бы посещение одной и тот же вершины несколько раз, т.е. например, путь в форме "восьмерки".

Comment: @AnT: гамильтонов путь петель не имеет по определению. Результат является гамильтоновым путём, потому что я так задачу поставил (сам вопрос не достаточно однозначен, но автор вопроса по-видимому согласился со мной).

Comment: @jfs Да именно это построения я и искал ) пасибо за ссылочку и пояснение)

Answer (score 2):

```
res = sorted(ids, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Сортировка по первому элементу в паре.

Comment: Нет дал немного простой список.

Comment: это не возвращает цепочку. Для примера в вопросе получается: `[[1, 203], [22, 5001], [203, 11], [333, 22], [5001, 1]]`, а нужно `[[333,22], [22,5001], [5001,1], [1,203], [203,11]]`

Comment: @jfs Автор дал пояснение лишь через 13 часов после написания ответа

Comment: *"главное условие чтобы вышла цепочка"*  присутствует в самой первой редакции вопроса (хотя первый пример не слишком показательный в вопросе был).

Answer (score 1):

```
ids = [[203, 11], [1, 203], [5001, 1], [333, 22], [22, 5001]]

res = []

while ids:
    if len(res) == 0:
        res.append(ids[0])
        ids.remove(ids[0])
    else:
        for i in range(len(res)):
            for c in range(len(ids)):
                if res[i][1] == ids[c][0]:
                    res.insert(res.index(i)+1,ids[c])
                    ids.remove(ids[c])
                    break
                elif res[0][0] == ids[c][1]:
                    res.insert(0,ids[c])
                    ids.remove(ids[c])
                    break
print(res)
```

Вот моё решение, данной задачки для сортировки списка цепочкой.

Comment: Представляю как желающие будут с этой картинки код переписывать, столько радости будет :)

Comment: Ваше решение неоптимально. Зачем в питоне реализовывать то, что уже 250 тысяч раз написано. Разумеется, если у человека есть задача реализовать сортировку -- другое дело. Но здесь история другая.

Comment: Ну мне нужно понять принцип, а про оптимальность речи не шло.

Comment: Это работает. На первый взгляд это выглядит как `O(n**4)` алгоритм. Не жертвуя простотой, можно улучшить алгоритм, до [`O(n**2)` (квадратичный по времени)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652848/23044).

Comment: [линейный алгоритм](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652848/23044) только немного сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, даже обычная сортировка будет работать так, как вы хотите:

```
res = sorted(ids)
```

Питон и так сравнивает списки сначала по первому элементу, и только если они равны, будет учитывать последующие элементы.

Comment: [[1, 203], [22, 5001], [203, 11], [333, 22], [5001, 1]]

Comment: [`sorted()` не возвращает цепочку.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652600/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-5%d1%852-5-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0/652848#comment934789_652610)